# Formula con agrupacion en Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Tengo un problema que no he podido resolver para generar un reporte en `crystal report` con `c#`.

Suponiendo que tengo la siguiente tabla en sql server

```
 - A B C D
 - G 3 2 1
 - G 5 6 7 
 - Y 2 5 6 
 - Y 3 2 3
```

El cual me interesa generar en `crystal report` agrupado por A y generando una nueva columna mediante una formula en crystal report del cual la columna nueva E va a ser la suma total y division por grupo entre la columna B y C

Ejemplo Grupo G:

```
B: 3 + 5 = 8 
C: 2 + 6 = 8
E: 8 / 8 = 1
```

Ejemplo Grupo Y:

```
B: 2 + 3 = 5 
C: 5 + 2 = 7
E: 5 / 7 = .71
```

Por lo que el reporte quedaría agrupado por la columna A:

```
 - A B C D E
 - G 8 8 1 1
 - Y 5 7 6 .71
```

Yo aplique la formula en crystal report para la agrupacion de A
{Comando.B / Comando.C}
Lo cual es incorrecto ya que me hace la division por cada registro del mismo grupo y me lo va sumando.

Busco que primero me haga toda la sumatoria de B y toda la sumatoria de C y al final dividirlo, ¿como lo aplico en una formula de `crystal report`?

Comment: Hola, por que mejor no agrupas en una vista en sql server y traes los datos procesados, y luego lo muestras en el reporte?

Comment: Si excelente opcion, solamente como el reporte ya lo había empezado así quería ver si se podría hacer con formulas crystal report.

Comment: Te entiendo, lo veo un poco mas incomodo asi. Recuerda que si lo haces como te digo también puedes reutilizar la vista en la aplicación.

Comment: Ok gracias por la referencia, pero finalmente pude y lo hice de este modo en una formula Sum ({Comando.B}, {Comando.A})/Sum ({Comando.C}, {Comando.A}) , la explicacion es sumo todo lo B por la agrupacion de A y lo divido por sumo todo lo C por la agrupacion de A. Saludos

Comment: Que bien, si puedes, agrega esa respuesta con detalles para que otra persona la use.